# Can a "type" be passed in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11

[A follow up to this question: Possible to instantiate object given its type in C++?

In Java, you can have a method parameter of type Class, and callers can pass in Foo.class.  I don't consider this aspect reflection, though what you can do with the passed-in Class obviously is.  Does C++ have any mechanism for passing in a "type"?  Since I know there is little/nothing I could do with that passed-in type, I suspect the answer is "no".

Obviously, templates provide this facility, but they're not what I'm looking for.

Comment: What do you want to do with this type object?

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like RTTI (run-time type identification) is what you're looking for. From http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C++_Programming/RTTI :

> The typeid operator, used to determine
>   the class of an object at runtime. It
>   returns a reference to a
>   std::type_info object, which exists
>   until the end of the program, that
>   describes the "object".

Comment: +1 because I forgot about `type_info` in my first revision in my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

No. This feature is part of "reflection" and is only possible in languages like Java which actually put information about classes in the compiled binary.

C++ (typically) does not actually store any information about classes at all in the resulting binary. (Excepting a few bits necessary for `std::type_info` to work)

In reality, there's nothing like the "Type" provided by Java and friends available in C++, and therefore you cannot pass it to a method.

If you want to pass a type to a method for the purpose of instantiating it, you can actually do this in a better way (this works with Java and friends too)

```
#include <memory>

struct IMyType
{
    virtual ~IMyType();
    virtual MyMethod();
};

struct IElementFactory
{
    virtual std::auto_ptr<IMyType> GetNewItem() const = 0;
    virtual ~IElementFactory();
};


void MyMethodThatAcceptsAType(const IElementFactory& factory)
{
    std::auto_ptr<IMyType> instance(factory.GetNewItem());
    //Use your instance like normal.
}
```

This is better even in Java land because this code maintains type safety, while the reflection based code does not.

Comment: So type_info is as close as you get in C++? (which isn't that close :-))

Comment: @Greencpp: Forgot about that. However, `std::type_info` is kind of useless for anything other than determining the most-derived-name of a particular instance variable. It's not even close to what's provided by "Type" in Java and friends languages.

Comment: @Greencpp: Err, misread your comment. Yes, `type_info` (and by extension `dynamic_cast`) is the only reflection-like feature found in C++.

Comment: @Greencpp: I have updated my answer with a workaround method (essentially use of the factory pattern). Let me know if that helps :)

Comment: @Billy: a pointer to function can be used in lieu of a `Factory` object or the newish `std::function<IMyType*()>`.

Answer (score 0):

How about [`RTTI`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-time_type_information) and [`typeid`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typeid)?